# How to display a complete text in Tkinter GUI in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a project that by the press of a button a text from another function will appear in GUI under that button .

The text is a function's result saved in a list.

I want to display the full text in the GUI window and if that cant fit in the small window, continue in a new line to fit in automatically

So far I've tried to display the result in a Label.grid but i can barrely see the first half sentence of my text.
I also changed the value of ipadx and ipady but this isnt wat i wanted as it displays all the sentences verticaly until its all displayed

```py
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter.messagebox import *

    global my_list
    my_list = ["This is the first sentence , ", "This is the second sentence ,", "this is the third sentence ,", "this is the last sentence "]

    def show_answer():
        Ans = my_list
        blank.insert(0, Ans)


    main = Tk()
    main.title('Programm')
    main.geometry('500x500+300+100')

    Button(main, text='Show', command=show_answer).grid(row=30, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

    Label(main, text="The text is").grid(row=2)
    blank = Entry(main)
    blank.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=50, ipady=50, sticky="NW")

    mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use tkinter.Text().

Example :

```
text_box = tkinter.Text(parent)
text_box.insert(tkinter.END, "some text...")
```

This displays the text and wraps the lines if too long.